# IEnumerable as URI-parameter to NET Core API

Tags: api, asp.net-core, .net-core, get, postman

What would be the best way of receiving `IEnumerable` as a URI-parameter for a **GET** endpoint in .NET Core 3.x

In deeper context: What I want to do is filtering out data depending on a number of GUIDs´.

So far I've got

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get(int allowedMissing, IEnumerable<Guid> ids)
    .
    .
    .
```

Im calling the endpoint using Postman as such:
`/endpoint?allowedMissing=2&ids=cab0cfcb-8eb2-4313-8064-e7b0841d4f8a&ids=b2b944c2-6b4a-4c32-9a2f-472b891e4843`

This results in a `415 Unsupported Media Type` without hitting any breakpoints inside the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so default for receiving `IEnumerable` in an Action seems to be in `body` and will require decorating the parameter with `FromQuery` if sent as query.

Changing to this solved my problem:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get(int allowedMissing, [FromQuery] IEnumerable<Guid> ids)
.
.
.
```